# In A Hierarchical Deterministic Wallet like metamask, are the additional child accounts completely private or can they be found to be from same master

Tags: metamask, wallets

Just wondering if anyone knows if this is undercover or if other viewers of my metamask will know the other accounts are related to my main.

Answer (score 0):

The child accounts can always be found from the same master, and in the same order that they were originally generated, **if** you know the seed phrase. This is the deterministic nature of the HD structure. Only the seed phrase holder can generate the ordered list, and so to your question, all (present & future) child accounts are private to an external viewer because they don't have the right ingredient to generate the next account in the chain.